# Subtracting sales from order in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have spent the last few hours trying to find something similar to the issue I am having and currently have smoke coming out of my ears!

I have two sheets, one with **orders** the second with **sales**.

I need help automatically *subtracting* from **orders** based on **sales**.

I am trying to develop a script that would run through every sale and if *location* and *item* are exactly the same, subtract quantity sold from the quantity ordered to give a "new due" quantity.

There will be sales with no order which is a non issue, but would be nice if those results could go to a different tab. Below is a summary of what is required in n00b terms.

`Sheet1` is **sold**, `Sheet2` is **order**.

If `Sheet1` *C2* & *F2* are same as any row in `Sheet2` (*A2*,*D2* are correlating fields) subtract `Sheet1` *G2*, from `Sheet2` *F2*.

I have added an example you can view here [Subtract if multiple conditions met](https://app.box.com/s/2m8nfjo8lieh5mfb9wgspy73f1bvzp0e)
https://app.box.com/s/2m8nfjo8lieh5mfb9wgspy73f1bvzp0e

On the results tab everything highlighted in yellow is what would have changed. Items not highlighted in yellow there was no sale. The green and red formatting was for reference and is not required if to difficult. (would be ideal) column H, is illustrating, if this is even possible, once the order quantity reaches 0, for the script to keep searching sheet for next order with same criteria and subtract remain quantity. Anything will help, I am currently doing this manually over the weekend and generally 150+ sales per week and is very time consuming.

In simple terms, I am trying to have a script go through each sale row and subtract quantity from the order sheet if the plant and part number are the same. I will sort the order sheet based on when they are do so it removes from correct order.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I can try giving you a formula, but it would make it much easier if you upload a sample of the workbook.

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Thank you for you help and interest in helping. I have uploaded an example sheet to show and edited my post to hopefully provide more clarity. I hope this helps explain what I am attempting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need VBA.

Look at SUMIFS()

I'm not allowed to look at your screenshots because my organization's reverse proxy doesn't allow access to app.box, but I'm assuming:

- Sheet1's "C" column contains locations.
- Sheet1's "F" column contains items.
- Sheet1's "G" column contains quantity sold.
- Sheet2's "A" column contains locations.
- Sheet2's "D" column contains items.
- Sheet2's "G" column contains quantity ordered.
- Sheet2's "H" column contains quantity due

While on sheet2, the total quantity sold for the item and location listed in row 2 is:

```
=IF(OR(A2="",D2=""),0,SUMIFS(Sheet1!G:G,Sheet1!C:C,A2,Sheet1:F:F,D2))
```

So the formula used for Sheet2!H2 would simply be subtracting this from the quantity ordered:

```
=G2-IF(OR(A2="",D2=""),0,SUMIFS(Sheet1!G:G,Sheet1!C:C,A2,Sheet1:F:F,D2))
```

Except that if the order is filled and a subsequent order for the same location and item has been at least partially filled, the total sold might be greater than the order in row 2, and Ordered - Sold would be less than zero! But that's an easy thing to guard against...

```
=MAX(0,G2-IF(OR(A2="",D2=""),0,SUMIFS(Sheet1!G:G,Sheet1!C:C,A2,Sheet1:F:F,D2)))
```

But that doesn't take into account any orders above the current line! We've got MIN(0,`ThisOrderQuantity`-`LocationItemQtySold`) when we should have MIN(0,`ThisOrderQuantity`+`PreviouslyOrderedQuantities`-`LocationItemQtySold`) The total of all orders above the current row in Sheet2 are

```
=OFFSET(G2,0,0,ROW()-2, 1)
```

... well... that will break on row 2. We want something that will work on all rows including the first. So let's protect ourselves in row 2.

```
=IF(ROW()<3,0,OFFSET(G2,0,0,ROW()-2, 1))
```

but that's all previous orders when we want only previous orders for the same location and item. We need another SUMIFS(). For Sheet2 row 10, this would be

```
=IF(ROW()<3,0,SUMIFS(OFFSET(G2,0,0,ROW()-2, 1),OFFSET(A:A,0,0,ROW()-2,1),A10,OFFSET(D:D,0,0,ROW()-2,1),D10))
```

Okay, so now we can combine them. For H2, draggable all the way down through the column, the formula would be:

```
=MAX(0,G2+IF(OR(A2="",D2=""),0,IF(ROW()<3,0,SUMIFS(OFFSET(G2,0,0,ROW()-2, 1),OFFSET(A:A,0,0,ROW()-2,1),A2,OFFSET(D:D,0,0,ROW()-2,1),D2))-SUMIFS(Sheet1!G:G,Sheet1!C:C,A2,Sheet1:F:F,D2)))
```

Except that if you have three orders for location/item and only the first one is filled, that third one's "due" quantity will be that order plus the second's order quantity! We need to make sure than if all previous orders aren't completely filled yet, that doesn't screw up our "Due" quantity. So we should add a MAX function so that what's due is never greater than what was ordered.

```
=MIN(G2,MIN(0,G2+IF(OR(A2="",D2=""),0,IF(ROW()<3,0,SUMIFS(OFFSET(G2,0,0,ROW()-2, 1),OFFSET(A:A,0,0,ROW()-2,1),A2,OFFSET(D:D,0,0,ROW()-2,1),D2))-SUMIFS(Sheet1!G:G,Sheet1!C:C,A2,Sheet1:F:F,D2))))
```

Paste that into H2, drag that formula down the rest of H, debug what I've done (because, spoiler, I have not), and you're done! No VBA required.

*(Warning: You mentioned a "non-issue" of sales without orders. Please consider that in such a case, if you **later** have an order, that order will be instantly filled!)*

Update 3-Feb-2017: Fixed issue with MIN and MAX; it should have been MAX and MIN.

Comment: this is almost perfect! The only error I found was from the very beginning you had Sheet1:F:F instead of Sheet1!F:F which was easily identifiable.

Everything worked all the way through the Min, as:
`=MIN(0,G2+IF(OR(A2="",D2=""),0,IF(ROW()<3,0,SUMIFS(OFFSET(G2,0,0,ROW()-2, 1),OFFSET(A:A,0,0,ROW()-2,1),A2,OFFSET(D:D,0,0,ROW()-2,1),D2))-SUMIFS(Sheet1!G:G,Sheet1!C:C,A2,Sheet1!F:F,D2)))` 

Which is where I need to stop as I would like to see the combined shortage of week 2 combined with week1. 

When I tried the max,  all I got was original due quantity on sheet2 G;G 

Thank you so much!

Comment: I spoke to soon, I apologize.

Comment: From what I see, the formula is only working if we over ship to the ordered quantity. For example:
Assuming plant and Item are a match; Quantity ordered is 10,10,10,10 and we invoice for 25 the next lines would reflect: -15,-5,0,0 when the desired result would be -15,-5,5,15.

Worth noting, assuming item and plant match, if order is for 25,50,25,25 and 60 were invoice, the formula would generate -25,0,-10,0.. Meaning if the amount over shipped is not >= next order it will skip and subtract from a the next.

Formula does not generate value >0

Comment: oops! I had MAX and MIN reversed! Fixed. But... from your above comment, that's not what you want. What I was going for was that if you ordered 10,10,10,10, and sold 25, the respective quantities due for each order should be 0, 0, 5, 10, meaning that the first and second orders were filled, the third order was half-filled, and none of the sales have been applied against the fourth.

Comment: Thank you for your help @JSmart523

Below is the exact formula I used and it worked exactly how I had hoped!

'`=MIN(G2,MAX(0,G2+IF(OR(A2="",D2=""),0,IF(ROW()<3,0,SUMIFS(OFFSET(G2,0,0,ROW()-2, 1),OFFSET(A:A,0,0,ROW()-2,1),A2,OFFSET(D:D,0,0,ROW()-2,1),D2))-SUMIFS(Sheet1!G:G,Sheet1!C:C,A2,Sheet1!F:F,D2))))`

Comment: Thanks! Please don't forget to select this as the answer to your question. :-)